# asp.net Membership - set comment field

Tags: asp.net-membership

The following code does not set the comment:

```
string userName = "yrtre.etre.423369a9-3e57-42da-934d-dae91f87a1e4";
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
user.Comment = "Test";
```

I get no exception.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to call UpdateUser to store your changes.

```
string userName = "yrtre.etre.423369a9-3e57-42da-934d-dae91f87a1e4";
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
user.Comment = "Test";
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```